# How to check if a point will intersect a line with ever increasing x axis?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

For example,
I am given a line from points (2,4) to (4,4).(the y axis remains constant).
Next I am given points with increasing values with respect to the $x$-axis such as (1,1) to (2,3) to (3,5) to (4,1).

On plotting the graph, it is quite clear that the given points will intersect the second and third segment. Therefore my answer here is 2(as it intersects twice).
How do I compute it as in, is there a general representation?

Comment: @amWhy please check the edit, if it goes through your head.

Comment: Yes, I now understand.  But I edited to indicate that the points have increasing values with respect to the x-axis.  Is the edit okay for you?

Comment: And in the second sentence, it is not the x-axis that is increasing, it is the $x$ coordinate in each of the successive points that is increasing.

Comment: Yes. Fine by me. as in the second  sentence, I apologize. Thank you.

Comment: Intermediate value theorem?

Comment: @dEmigOd I'm not sure if this theorem would help me in counting the number of times the line will intersect the curve. It is also not certain that the lines will intersect each other at all. Check the update.

Comment: If you’re asking specifically about straight line segments, there are well-established algorithms and plenty of sample code for computing their intersections that can be found with a simple Internet search. Try something like “line segment intersection algorithm.”

Comment: According to algorithm provided on the internet, I would have to input the first line co-ordinates in every segment and that would not be time/space efficient.

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/problems/LAZER Here is the statement.